# How to sum a inverval of rows in Pandas Series?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, and I need to sum the bimonthly values for each City ('Municipio' Column).

Like in 'Acrelândia' on the first bimester in 2019, it should give the value 1.762.356,65.
I don't have any idea to do this efficiently. Someone can help me?

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
        Município   UF   Mês  ...       2017       2018       2019
0      Acrelândia   AC   1.0  ...  748780.61  740381.02  861747.15
1      Acrelândia   AC   2.0  ...  850714.86  880849.33  900609.50
2      Acrelândia   AC   3.0  ...  617978.20  642454.98  711703.16
3      Acrelândia   AC   4.0  ...  685174.68  661647.05  718405.94
4      Acrelândia   AC   5.0  ...  772153.06  783355.47  825357.96
...           ...  ...   ...  ...        ...        ...        ...
66824     Xambioá   TO   9.0  ...  440157.71  447923.66  522026.46
66825     Xambioá   TO  10.0  ...  478002.52  445073.83  564305.39
66826     Xambioá   TO  11.0  ...  473037.80  431933.80  633013.36
66827     Xambioá   TO  12.0  ...  568319.87  762546.79       0.00
66828         NaN  NaN   NaN  ...        NaN        NaN        NaN

[66829 rows x 16 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `shift`

```
import numpy as np
df['2017 (Bi-monthly)'] = np.where(df['Mês'] > 1, df['2017'] + df['2017'].shift(1), '')
df['2018 (Bi-monthly)'] = np.where(df['Mês'] > 1, df['2018'] + df['2018'].shift(1), '')
df['2019 (Bi-monthly)'] = np.where(df['Mês'] > 1, df['2019'] + df['2019'].shift(1), '')
```

You won't be able to calculate the first month of 2017, but you can calculate the first month of 2018 and 2019. To do that, try the below; admittedly, I couldn't confirm that the code below works as I couldn't test since you pasted an image. If you could copy and paste the actual data instead of an image, I could fix the below code if it doesn't work:

```
df.loc[df['Mês'] == 1, '2018 (Bi-monthly)'] = df.loc[df['Mês'] == 12]['2017'] + df.loc[df['Mês'] == 1]['2018']
df.loc[df['Mês'] == 1, '2019 (Bi-monthly)'] = df.loc[df['Mês'] == 12]['2018'] + df.loc[df['Mês'] == 1]['2019']
```